# Formatting column in Excel using EPPlus Lib C#.Net

Tags: excel, c#-4.0, datatable, epplus

My **DataTable** has the information **from a Data base table** and I'm **able to dump** the DataTable value into Excel using EPPlus lib.

Now, **I want to format the column name in the Excel by setting range(lets say A1 to Z1) of cells to certain orientation (45 degree) and give some color to it**

I'm using VS2010 for my development.
[image: Added image as an example]
How can I do this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use the `TextRotation` property:

```
worksheet.Cells["A1:Z1"].Style.TextRotation = 45;
```

> How to give color to it?

```
var range = worksheet.Cells["A1:Z1"];
var fill = range.Style.Fill;
fill.PatternType = ExcelFillStyle.LightGray;
fill.PatternColor.SetColor(Color.Beige);
fill.BackgroundColor.SetColor(Color.White);
```

> How can I do: Format-> "AutoFit Column width" using code?

```
worksheet.Cells["A1:Z1"].AutoFitColumns();
```

Comment: Thanks.I will try this.How to give color to it??

Comment: @bapirout: I've edited my answer. Have a look if that works now since i cannot test it. I've looked at some old VB.NET code where i've used the `range.Style.Fill`.

Comment: Thanks..Its Working.Some minor change is there..I think, I can do this now.